# How do I add tooltips to a palette?

Tags: palettes, tooltip

The CreatingPalettes help file shows how to create a palette with special symbols:

```
CreatePalette[
  Grid[
    Partition[
        PasteButton[Style[#, 12], RawBoxes[#],ImageSize->24]&
      /@
        {"π", "E", "I", "∞", "°", "*", "/", "->", ":>", "==", 
         "!=", "<=", ">=", "∈", "∍", "¬", "∧", "∨", "⋃", "⋂"},
      5],
    Spacings->{0,0}]];
```

I am trying to create a palette that includes some special symbols, and I also want to include tooltips. But, if, for example, I replace `"Pi"` with `Tooltip ["Pi", "3.14"]`, the tooltip `3.14` displays nicely, but when I click on `Pi`, the result includes the word `Tooltip` along with the label:

```
Tooltip["π", "3.14"]
```

I have tried every which way for several days to add tooltips that behave. Meanwhile I have added lots and lots of other features, but this one defies me. I know it can't be hard but ...

Comment: I just found a way to make this work, but it's convoluted. I'd prefer to hear of a more straight-forward answer.

Comment: I am not very familiar with palette construction, but I wonder if you would have more luck by wrapping `PasteButton` within `Tooltip`, instead of the other way round. Unfortunately I'm on mobile and can't test it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach seems top work. I have reduced your code to something more like a minimal working example.

```
With[{chrs = {"π", "E", "I", "∞"}, 
      tips = {"π tip", "E tip", "I tip", "∞ tip"}}},
  CreatePalette[
    Grid[
      {MapThread[
         Tooltip,
         {PasteButton[Style[#1, 12], RawBoxes[#1], ImageSize -> 24] & /@ chrs, 
          tips}]},
      Spacings -> {0, 0}]]];
```

Comment: This is very nice, and I see how it follows MarcoB's suggestion as well. I plan to use this if I can wrap all the additional structure and data that I have already built into my palette. I don't wish to lose all that effort. If not, at least I now have my own less straight-forward solution to use. I'll post back when I figure this out. Thank you both!

Comment: I was easily able to embed this in my current template, so this definitely solves my problem. Because I have multiple grids, I had to  move your "with" statement inside your "CreatePalette" and "Grid" statements (and, actually, inside other wrapper statements I have), but it worked right "out-of-the-box". It would have taken me days, if ever, to understand how to move Tooltip in front of PasteButton, so I really appreciate your showing me how to do this.